# Mocking static methods in c# using Rhino Mock

Tags: c#, .net, rhino-mocks

What is the best approach for mocking out a static class in c#. For instance:

```
String appPath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath;
```

I want to mock this but will need to wrap it in a class with an interface, what is the best approach and does this approach work for all static methods?

Will this approach not make a lot of allmost pointless interfaces and classes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the best approach for mocking out a static class in c#

The best approach is to hide those static calls behind abstractions. Those can be faked. For instance:

```
public interface IApplicationPhysicalPathProvider
{
    string ApplicationPhysicalPath { get; }
}

public class AspNetApplicationPhysicalPathProvider : IApplicationPhysicalPathProvider
{
    public string ApplicationPhysicalPath 
    {
        get { return HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath; }
    }
}
```

This advice holds for any mocking framework and even if you don't use a mocking framework at all.